# Can't pass the checkout process

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

I'm having this error on my website `EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type commerce_line_item. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7866 of /var/www/xxx/xxx/includes/common.inc).` and I don't know why it showed up recently.

Any one has encountered this error?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) It's not possible for us to debug this for you, as we would need full access to your site and code base. Please see the comments in the duplicate to get a general idea of what's going wrong, so you'll be able to debug your own installation

Comment: Thank you very much Clive for the answer, i'm looking into it as we speak! :)

Comment: Hi, you can close this question, i've opted for a fresh install, the other one had way too many errors and WSOD!

Thank you for all the help! :)